# Testing root component: Angular 2 testing

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I'm trying to test my angular 2 app which obviously has a root component. The root component has nothing technical in its class body, it is just importing the child components and calling child components in its html file (with child component tags). Because it doesn't have any 'functionality' except calling its children components, what is the best practice to test it?

Comment: Mock out the child components and make sure they *do* get called?

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you direct to an example or resource where we can verify if a component contains another component